# Error in serial communication using C

Tags: c, serial-port, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux

Am trying to establish a serial communication between a raspberry pi and my windows PC.
In my raspberry, I am running a C code wich read from serial port. The communication between two parts is established and I can receive data, but the problem is that the received packet is not the same sended. For example if I send from my computer 0xAA, I am receiving on the Raspberry side some thing like 0x6FFFFFAA, ans so on. I don't know from where this 6FFFFF is coming?? It is repeated even with other packets! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: In my code I am using a variable x declared as unsigned int. Then I am catching the serial data using the function read(port, &x,1). When printing x as int (using %d) I am getting a big number, but normally I will get 41 for the A. And when printing it as hex I get this 6FFFFFAA

Comment: FYI the **read()** function that you call does not directly access the serial port.  The serial port driver is copying the received bytes to a system buffer, and then **read()** copies those bytes from that system buffer to your buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, you're doing this:

```
unsigned int x;
...
read(port, &x,1);
```

This won't work, since you're reading one byte but an `int` is at least 2 or 4 bytes on most systems.  So one byte of the `int` contains the value you want but the rest contain garbage.

If you're reading data a byte at a time, you should declare `x` as an `unsigned char` which is one byte.

If you want to read two or more bytes at a time, you'd define a character array to read into:

```
char buffer[size];
int count, i;

count = read(port, buffer, size);
if (count == -1) {
    perror("read failed");
    exit(1);
}
for (i=0;i<count;i++) {
    // process buffer[i]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I see now why it does not work. But what if I want to read two bytes at time, how can I do it?

Comment: @HelmiROMDHANI size = 2;

Comment: ..even then, it may only read one byte.

Comment: @HelmiROMDHANI: That is a **serial** communication link which presents data per byte. You cannot read two or more bytes "at a time". However, you can ask to get any many bytes as you want. Guess what the `size` argument is for?

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned int` is larger than the size `1` which you gave as the number of bytes to read as argument to `read`. Hence only one byte was read into the `unsigned int`, and the rest is basically uninitialized or leftover data. Read to an `unsigned char`, i.e.,

```
unsigned char x;
read(port, &x, 1);
```

You can still print it with `printf` as before.